# Moving non-adjacent cells in excel

Tags: excel

I just wonder, is there any way to move non-adjacent cells (upward/downward/left or right) in excel?
I have multiple entries for gene accession numbers and I want to move certain of these entries/cells but dont know how to do it.

Comment: Have you tried pressing `Control` + selecting the cells you need, then cut / copy /move and paste.

Comment: @Harun24hr, We cannot drag non-adjacent cells.

Comment: @Redox, We cannot cut/paste non ajecent cells

Comment: Is the worksheet protected? If it is protected probably you can't

Comment: This is weird indeed: you select two adjacent cells, using "Shift" and you press "Shift+Delete", no problem. You do the same with two adjacent cells, using "Control" and you press "Shift+Delete", you get the error message "This can't be done on a multiple range selection" :-)